# detect audioelement using Modernizr

Tags: javascript

I am using html 5 audio element in my code:

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
```

I am using this object to play audio from a specific source.

How to detect the above code using modernizr?

Any answer will be appreciated .Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can just check for `audioElement` instead:

```
if (audioElement) { ... audioElement is defined ... }
```

... as you define this element in the `<head>` section, it effectively becomes global.

This code detects whether you've defined audioElement or not. If you need to detect whether or not HTML5 audio is supported by browser, I suppose you should test `Modernizr.audio` [property](http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-html5), like this:

```
if (Modernizr.audio) {
  var audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = Modernizr.audio.ogg ? 'background.ogg' :
              Modernizr.audio.mp3 ? 'background.mp3' :
                                    'background.m4a'
            ;
  audio.play();
}
```

Here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d764Y/1/); instead of 'something.mp3' you should use your own link, of course. )

Comment: is it just if(audioElement) or if(Modernizr.audioElement) ?

Comment: actually i need the code for modernizr as i need to detect the browser feature.

Comment: if(audioElement)
{
    alert("audio support");
 var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
 var sou='http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=hello';
    audioElement.setAttribute('src',sou);
    audioElement.play();
}

Comment: this code is for chrome.so i need to detect chrome audioelement support feature and based on that i have to use this code

Comment: even modernizr.audio doesnt work.ok any idea of how to detect activex object using modernizr?

Comment: the example which you have given is different from the audio element which i have told you right?

Comment: yaa..i checked with that..actually i am using google tranlator to retrieve the mp3 so the link changes dynamically based on user input.So is there any way to define the audio.src dynamically?

Comment: Yes, of course: just assign the link (or some value parsed off it) to the `audio.src` instead of a fixed string.

Comment: if(Modernizr.audio)
{
 alert('Audio is supported');
    var audio1 = new audio();
    audio1.src = 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=hello';
    audio1.play();
}

Comment: No, it won't work like this. The link is for the page, and audio snippet is just a single element of it. You should either check Google Translate API whether they give direct links for audio translations or not, or parse the answer for this link.

Comment: oh ok i ll try n let u know whether it works.anyway thanks for sparing time for helping me.

Comment: any idea of detecting activex object using modernizr?